# Import Tableau csv into Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, import, pyspark, tableau-api

I exported some data from tableau's underlaying data set as csv. When I try to view it with `less`, it says that it `may be a binary file.  See it anyway?`

However, when I do a

`cat file.csv | cut -d ',' -f 1`

It shows human readable data (although it doesn't print the first field, but the entire line).

So I attempt to load it in Spark 2 with:

```
data = sqlContext.read.csv( "file.csv" )
data.show(5)
```

And I get:

```
+--------------------+
|                 _c0|
+--------------------+
|��Cluster ...|
+--------------------+
```

Any idea how I can make a dataframe out of this supposed binary file?

Comment: please try to expert your tableu's data to CSV using the methods in this link: http://www.vizwiz.com/2014/03/the-greatest-tableau-tip-ever-exporting.html - do you get read-able csv now?

Answer (score 1):

in the end i figured out it must have been a UTF-16 text file. so i used

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT file.csv > file-utf8.csv
```

to convert the file to utf-8/ascii and the converted file loaded fine.